# Where exactly is the Check Engine Light connector on a 1997 Honda Honda Civic?

Tags: troubleshooting, cel, interior, sensor, dtc

The check engine light on my 1997 Honda Civic lit up. I came across a method for troubleshooting (http://honda-tech.com/showthread.php?t=1901557) but I'm having trouble finding the connector.  Can someone please tell me where this connector is?  I've looked on both sides of the interior but can't seem to find it.

Here's some examples of what the connector looks like (supposedly).

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I had been searching the internet for hours trying to find out where this OBD2 connector was located and you showed me exactly where it was. I was able to jump the connector and pull the code. It is 67 which I believe is either a faulty secondary O2 sensor or bad catalytic converter. Since it is running fine and getting great gas mileage, I do not think that the converter is the problem so I will replace the sensor and hope that the engine light problem will be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just in front of the front passenger side door, under the dashboard. It might be stuck down behind the carpet a ways.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the passenger side foot kick panel covering the ECU you will see it there.  On the 97 it is the blue 2 pin plug.